# How to convert every Json array element's value from decimal (105.0) to integer (105) in Karate?

Tags: arrays, json, karate

I working on to create a **JSON comparator script using Karate** which compares 2 JSON responses coming from different source.

My script is currently failing due to **mismatch in "price" values**.

Please refer following json response and observe "price" key :

```
[
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8754",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8754_SL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8750",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8750_SL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8747",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110.0,
        "typeCode": "8747_SL"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

I need to convert all **"price"** value to integer (by ignoring or removing .0) as below (So that both JSON responses will be identical):

```
[
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8754",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8754_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8754_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160,
        "typeCode": "8754_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8754_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8754_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8754_SL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8750",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8750_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8750_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160,
        "typeCode": "8750_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8750_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8750_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8750_SL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "1414::2::8747",
    "value": [
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "G1",
        "description": "GOLD 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8747_G1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "GL",
        "description": "GOLD",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8747_GL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "MM",
        "description": "MM LOUNGE",
        "price": 160,
        "typeCode": "8747_MM"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "P1",
        "description": "PLATINUM 1",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8747_P1"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "PL",
        "description": "PLATINUM",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8747_PL"
      },
      {
        "seatingType": "fixed",
        "areaCatCode": "SL",
        "description": "SILVER",
        "price": 110,
        "typeCode": "8747_SL"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

Currently, both the JSON responses are identical **excluding "price" key**. In order to pass the script, every value of "price" key should not have trailing ".0" in it.

Please Help !!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Peter If I want to set parseInt values back to JSON. How should I do it ?

Comment: And def test = karate.map(karate.jsonPath(new_areas_expected_pairs,"$..price"), function(x){ return (parseInt(~~(1*x))); })
And print test

Output will be in below format :
[
  110,
  110,
  160,
  110,
  110,
  110,
  110,
  110,
  160,
  110,
  110
]

Comment: read the docs please. it is called a `README` for a reason: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms